# Function setting on SPLC780D LCD

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, i2c, lcd

I'm drawing a bit of a blank with this. I have a [1602A-1 16x2](http://www.openhacks.com/uploadsproductos/eone-1602a1.pdf) LCD screen hooked up to an [i2c port expander chip](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf).

I'm using the screen in 4 bit mode so I have DB4-7 hooked up to GPIO 0-3 respectively.

I have also hooked up RS, R/W and E to other GPIO pins.

[image]

I can see the function set binary string is 001010xx to set 4 bit mode with 2 display lines and 5x8 dots display mode. I am thus setting the GPIO 0-3 pins to 0010 and then setting the enable pin high. I set the enable pin back to low and set the GPIO 0-3 pins to 1000. Again, I pulse the enable pin.

All the time, the RS and R/W pins are low to signify Instruction Input & Write, respectively.

I've tested the pins output with a multimeter so I'm confident that they are high and low when they should be... however it's just not working. The screen does not change to 2 lines nor can I send 4 bit commands in a similar way, following this.

Anyone have any insights?

Comment: It would help to provide the specific I2C expander model/datasheet and a rough schematic of the connection rather than a text description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the bottom 4 bits of the data tied to ground?

You should first reset the LCD by sending the 0x30 command three times. Although the LCD will still be in 8-bit mode the bottom four bits are hardwired to 0 so you don't need to send the separate nibbles.

Now send the 0x20 command, again in 8 bit mode. When this command finishes the LCD will be in 4 bit mode.

To enable 2 rows, send command 0x28. Now you are in 4 bit mode so you need to send two nibbles.

Writing to the LCD through a port expander will require up to **eight** writes to the port expander for each byte written to the LCD. This is necessary because of the timing sequence required for the various control signals. The sequence I use is:

1. Set the appropriate value on RS for data or command
2. Set EN high
3. Put bottom nibble of data/command on D[7:4]
4. Bring EN low
5. Bring EN high
6. Put top nibble on D[7:4]
7. Bring EN low
8. Bring RS low (optional)

Remember that it takes a long time for the LCD to process a command and you must wait for it to finish before starting another command or sending another data byte. The LCD I am using needs many microseconds for some commands so I am using a system tick of 1ms and writing a byte at every tick interrupt. If you don't want to wait you need to observe the BUSY status on D7 instead.